# SyntaxError: Unexpected token S, AngularJS, Spring

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring

I'm making a simple establishment of registration that must have data and a logo. In tests could transmit the file and the data separately but when trying to send them together the following error occurs:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token S
at Object.parse (native)
at qc (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:14:245)
at Zb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:76:423)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:77:283
at r (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:7:302)
at Zc (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:77:265)
at c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:78:414)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:112:113
at n.$get.n.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:126:15)
at n.$get.n.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:123:106)
```

The Angular Controller

```
angular.module('EntregaJaApp').controller('EstabelecimentoController', ['$scope', '$http','Upload', function($scope, $http,Upload){

$scope.salvar = function(){
         Upload.upload({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/site-web/gerencial/estabelecimento/salvar',
            file: $scope.picFile[0],
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}, // only for html5
            data: {'estabelecimento': $scope.estabelecimento}
        });
}}
```

The Spring Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/gerencial/estabelecimento")
public class EstabelecimentoController {

@Autowired
private EstabelecimentoService estabelecimentoService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/salvar",  method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?>  salvar(Estabelecimento estabelecimento,@RequestParam(value="file", required=false) MultipartFile file){
    try {
          byte[] bytes;

            if (!file.isEmpty()) {
                 bytes = file.getBytes();
                //store file in storage
            }

            System.out.println(String.format("receive %s from %s", file.getOriginalFilename(), estabelecimento.getNome()));
        estabelecimentoService.salvar(estabelecimento);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(MensagensGerais.SUCESSO_SALVAR,HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>((StringUtil.eVazia(e.getMessage()) ? MensagensGerais.ERRO_CONSULTAR : e.getMessage()),HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
   }
```

Comment: Since the error is in parse I'm guessing the data being sent to Angular is not valid or what it is expecting. Are you able to show what you are transmitting?

Comment: I'm trying to transmitting  {"nome":"Test"}, also tried JSON.parse () and angular.toJson (), but there was the same error.

Comment: Check if your JSON data is valid...

Answer (score 0):

did you missed the return type annotation? Like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/salvar",  method = RequestMethod.POST)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ResponseEntity<?>  salvar(Estabelecimento estabelecimento,@RequestParam(value="file", required=false) MultipartFile file){...}
```

Comment: can you use fiddler o wireshark to see the server response?

Comment: Response Headers
view parsed
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 17

Comment: ------WebKitFormBoundaryskA2p1hIUyDUePmY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"

{"estabelecimento":{"nome":"aaa"}}
------WebKitFormBoundaryskA2p1hIUyDUePmY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="mito.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the request specifies an Accept Header "application/json", it seems that the Strings are not correctly serialized (by Spring?). Angular versions prior to 1.3.x seem to have been generous, but now an exception is thrown when the response is not correct JSON. I have added the following response `transformer` to my app:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse.unshift(function(data, headersGetter, status){
            var contentType = headersGetter('Content-Type');
            if(angular.isString(contentType) && contentType.startsWith('application/json')){
                try {
                    angular.fromJson(data);
                } catch(e){
                    var mod = '"'+data+'"';
                    try {
                        angular.fromJson(mod);
                        return mod;
                    }
                    catch(e){
                        return data;
                    }
                }
                return data;
            }
            else{
                return data;
            }
        });
```

It transforms a JS string to a JSON string object by wrapping it in additional `"`.